# how to make stuff visible on bootstrap in different sizes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I want to do something like this
in my web site i want to see 3 different option when enter the site.
now when i change sizes i need to see different stuff.

***In XL I need to see all the stuff, like in the picture.***

[image: xl]

***in MD to hide the pictures and see 2 rows***
[image: md]

***in XS to see in 2 columns.***
[image: xs]

now I succeed to to the XL, `<div class="col d-none d-xl-block d-xxl-none ">`

but the other two options I don't know what to do to make it works.
i did in both of them

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
```

what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want this structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4  col-xxl-4">
      The Wire...
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-xxl-4">
      images
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4  col-xxl-4">
      list
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, in your description - you said 2 rows in MD and 2 columns in XS - I think it's the other way around (like on your images).